# env-cmd path error when running npm run dev

Tags: node.js, npm, environment-variables

I'm about to deploy my app. There are MONGODB_URL, PORT in dev.env under /config/, and I've installed env-cmd.
My dev script looks like:

```
   "dev": "env-cmd ./config/dev.env nodemon index.js"
```

When I go 'npm run dev' in terminal, it says:

"Error: Failed to find .env file at default paths: [./.env,./.env.js,./.env.json]
    at getEnvFile blah blah"

Can somebody help please

Answer (score 2):

Change it as `"dev": "env-cmd -f ./config/dev.env nodemon index.js"`